# How do I populate a list field in a model from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo.MVC project.  The view has a model with a field of type List<>.  I want to populate the List from a Javascript function.  I've tried several ways, but can't get it working.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

So here is my model:

```
public class Dashboard
{
    public List<Note> ListNotes { get; set; }
}
```

I use the ListNotes on the view like this:

```
foreach (Note note in Model.ListNotes)
{
    @Html.Raw(note.NoteText)
}
```

This works if I populate Model.ListNotes in the controller when the view starts...

```
public ActionResult DashBoard(string xsr, string vst)
    {
        var notes = rep.GetNotesByCompanyID(user.ResID, 7, 7);
        List<Koorsen.Models.Note> listNotes = new List<Koorsen.Models.Note>();

        Dashboard employee = new Dashboard
        {
            ResID = intUser,
            Type = intType,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            ListNotes = listNotes
        };

        return View(employee);
    }
```

... but I need to populate ListNotes in a Javascript after a user action.

Here is my javascript to make an ajax call to populate ListNotes:

```
function getReminders(e)
{
    var userID = '@ViewBag.CurrUser';
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/WoApi/GetReminders/" + userID,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (notes)
        {
            // Need to assign notes to Model.ListNotes here
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the method it calls with the ajax call.  I've confirmed ListNotes does have the values I want; it is not empty.

```
public List<Koorsen.Models.Note> GetReminders(int id)
    {
        var notes = rep.GetNotesByCompanyID(id, 7, 7);
        List<Koorsen.Models.Note> listNotes = new List<Koorsen.Models.Note>();

        foreach (Koorsen.OpenAccess.Note note in notes)
        {
            Koorsen.Models.Note newNote = new Koorsen.Models.Note()
            {
                NoteID = note.NoteID,
                CompanyID = note.CompanyID,
                LocationID = note.LocationID,
                NoteText = note.NoteText,
                NoteType = note.NoteType,
                InternalNote = note.InternalNote,
                NoteDate = note.NoteDate,
                Active = note.Active,
                AddBy = note.AddBy,
                AddDate = note.AddDate,
                ModBy = note.ModBy,
                ModDate = note.ModDate
            };

            listNotes.Add(newNote);
        }

        return listNotes;
    }
```

If ListNotes was a string, I would have added a hidden field and populated it in Javascript.  But that didn't work for ListNotes.  I didn't get an error, but the text on the screen didn't change.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ListNotes)
...
...
$("#ListNotes").val(notes);
```

I also tried

```
@Model.ListNotes = notes; // This threw an unterminated template literal error

document.getElementById('ListNotes').value = notes;
```

I've even tried refreshing the page after assigning the value:

```
window.location.reload();
```

and refreshing the panel bar the code is in

```
var panelBar = $("#IntroPanelBar").data("kendoPanelBar");
panelBar.reload();
```

Can someone explain how to get this to work?

I don't know if this will cloud the issue, but the reason I need to populate the model in javascript with an ajax call is because Model.ListNotes is being used in a Kendo Panel Bar control and I don't want Model.ListNotes to have a value until the user expands the panel bar.

Here's the code for the panel bar:

```
@{
    @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar().Name("IntroPanelBar")
        .Items(items =>
        {
        items
        .Add()
        .Text("View Important Notes and Messages")
        .Expanded(false)
        .Content(
            @<text>
                    @RenderReminders()
            </text>
                );
        }
        )
    .Events(e => e
    .Expand("getReminders")
    )
    )
}
```

Here's the helper than renders the contents:

```
@helper RenderReminders()
{
    if (Model.ListNotes.Count <= 0)
    {
         @Html.Raw("No Current Messages");
    }
    else
    {
         foreach (Note note in Model.ListNotes)
         {
               @Html.Raw(note.NoteText)
               <br />
         }
    }
}
```

The panel bar and the helpers work fine if I populate Model.ListNotes in the controller and pass Model to the view.  I just can't get it to populate in the javascript after the user expands the panel bar.

Comment: This is a classic problem of devs who doesn't understand the state of the technologies involved in the app. Javascript can only send data to the controller via ajax, hence you can only *assign* a C# value from JS by that way. You have to access the JS values only by JS in your view, and post it to the controller to use in any other view/request in future, but in the same context you are no able to do so.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a value to an input element type="hidden" then display it to the user?

Comment: Assign the value to a hidden control and display it?  Yes, that's one of the things I've tried.  All I really need to do is change the content of the panel bar from javascript.  I've tried various ways, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will do it for you. I will provide a small working example I believe you can easily extend to meet your needs. I would recommend writing the html by hand instead of using the helper methods such as @html.raw since @html.raw is just a tool to generate html in the end anyways. You can write html manually accomplish what the helper methods do anyway and I think it will be easier for you in this situation. If you write the html correctly it should bind to the model correctly (which means it won't be empty on your post request model) So if you modify that html using javascript correctly, it will bind to your model correctly as well.

Take a look at some of these examples to get a better idea of what I am talking about:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

So to answer your question...
You could build a hidden container to hold your list values like this (make sure this container is inside the form):

```
<div id="ListValues" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Then put the results your ajax post into a javascript variable (not shown).
Then in javascript do something like this:

```
        $('form').off('submit'); //i do this to prevent duplicate bindings depending on how this page may be rendered futuristically as a safety precaution.
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) { //on submit, modify the form data to include the information you want inside of your ListNotes
            
            var data = getAjaxResults(); //data represents your ajax results. You can acquire and format that how you'd like I will use the following as an example format for how you could save the results as JSON data: [{NoteID ="1",CompanyID ="2"}] 
            
            let listLength = data.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
                $('#ListValues').append('<input type="text" name="ListNotes['+i+'].NoteID " value="' + data.NoteID +'" />') 
                $('#ListValues').append('<input type="text" name="ListNotes['+i+'].CompanyID " value="' + data.CompanyID +'" />') 
                 //for your ajax results, do this for each field on the note object
            }
            
        })
```

That should do it! After you submit your form, it should automatically model bind to you ListNotes! You will be able to inpsect this in your debugger on your post controller action.